# Evaluate the definite integral $\int_0^a (a^2 + x^2)^\frac{5}{2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, trigonometric-integrals

I'm stuck on this definite integral problem. I need some constructive hint to proceed further.

$$\int_0^a (a^2 + x^2)^\frac{5}{2} dx$$

Substituting
$$x = a \cot\theta,$$
I have converted this integral to $$\int_0^a (a \csc\theta)^5 dx.$$

Now I'm unable to proceed further. Kindly help

Comment: Use http://calc101.com/deriving_reduction_5.html

Comment: Additionally, you forgot to substitute in a new differential.  You should be able to calculate that $\mathrm{d}x=-a\csc^2\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta$, which changes your overall integral a bit.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee can I apply that to definite integral problem also. Because they have illustrated it using indefinite integral.

Comment: @user109256 You can. But you need to take care of the limits. In fact, with the change $x=a \cot\theta$, the limits change from $(0,a)$ to $(\frac{\pi}{4},\frac{\pi}{2})$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Substitute $x=a\sinh(t)$.

$$a^6\int\cosh^6(t)\,dt=\frac{a^6}{32}\int(\cosh(6t)+6\cosh(4t)+15\cosh(2t)+40)\,dt.$$

Answer (score 1):

Utilize the reduction formula
$$\int_0^a \frac{x^n}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}dx=I_n=\frac{\sqrt2 a^6}
n -\frac{(n-1)a^2}nI_{n-2}
$$
to reduce the integral
\begin{align}
\int_0^a (a^2 + x^2)^\frac{5}{2} dx
= &\int_0^a \frac{(a^2 + x^2)^3}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}dx\\
= &\int_0^a \frac{x^6+3a^2x^4+3a^4x^2+a^6}{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}dx\\
=& \ \frac{67\sqrt2}{48}a^6+\frac5{16}a^6 I_0
\end{align}
where $ I_0=\int_0^a\frac1{\sqrt{a^2+x^2}}dx=\sinh^{-1}1 $.

Answer (score 0):

In $\theta$ the integral is
$$a^6 \int_\frac\pi4^\frac\pi2 \csc^7 \theta \,d\theta.$$
Now apply the [reduction formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae#Transcendental_functions)
$$\int \csc^m \theta \,d\theta = - \frac{1}{m - 1} \csc^{m - 2} \cot \theta + \frac{m - 2}{m - 1} \int \csc^{m - 2} \theta \,d\theta ,$$
which specializes for our limits to
$$\int_\frac\pi4^\frac\pi2 \csc^m \theta \,d\theta = 2^{\frac{m}2 - 1} + \frac{m - 2}{m - 1} \int_\frac\pi4^\frac\pi2 \csc^{m - 2} \theta \,d\theta ,$$
three times to express the integral in terms of
$$\int_\frac\pi4^\frac\pi2 \csc \theta \,d\theta = -\log |\csc \theta + \cot \theta| \Big\vert_\frac\pi4^\frac\pi2 = \operatorname{arsinh} 1 = \log(1 + \sqrt 2).$$

> Performing these computations yields $$\boxed{a^6 \left(\frac{67 \sqrt 2}{48} + \frac{5}{16} \operatorname{arsinh} 1\right)}.$$